# Ionic Angular 2: Render template (+model) to html string

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, render

I know very little about Ionic and Angular 2. The whole Ionic+Angular 2 setup works fine, but everything works 'behind the scene' so I don't know how to take advantage of the framework to do some simple thing. I want to render a component but to an HTML string, I don't want it to automatically replace the current page.

I need something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: '???',  // i don't need this
  template: '<div>{{name}},{{count}}</div>'
})
export class MySpecialPage {
   name: string;
   count:number;

   constructor() {}

   setInfo(name:string, count:number){...}
}
```

Then in some other part of the code I want to use this component, set the info and render it to a simple HTML string without injecting it to the document.
Something like this:

```
import {MySpecialPage} from './my-special-page';

let html:string = render(MySpecialPage, {name:'John', count:43});
```

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I am not sure it would be possible. What is your base requirement exactly? Maybe you could find a much better solution. I might be an XYproblem . See http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I'm using some Cordova plugin and one of it's parameters is an HTML string (as a content of some external component that is not under my control )

Comment: Could you tell me which plugin, if you don't mind?

Comment: Yes no problem: cordova-plugin-drawoverapps (with few modifications) . I know what are my alternatives, but I thought this is a common and 'easy to solve' problem.